# Modify object value inside self invoking function

Tags: javascript, function

I want to build a basic JS library. 
I have a self invoking function which contains an object.

```
var test = (function (window) {

var defaults = {
    container: 'app',
    size: 500
};

function init() {
    var div = document.getElementById(defaults.container);
    var playerTemplate = 
    `<div class="container">
        <h1>hi</h1>
    </div>`;
    div.innerHTML = playerTemplate;
};

return {
    init: init
};

})(window);
```

When I run this function, I want to pass an object and change defaults object in of it. How can i do this?

like this:

```
test.init({size: 300});
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Start with adding a parameter to your `init` function…

Comment: You can use `Object.assign` to merge your `defaults` object with the object from the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Object.assign method to overwrite default values

```
var test = (function (window) {

var defaults = {
    container: 'app',
    size: 500
};

function init(options) {
    const opts = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);

    var div = document.getElementById(opts.container);
    var playerTemplate =
        `<div class="container">
        <h1>hi</h1>
    </div>`;
    div.innerHTML = playerTemplate;
};

 return {
    init: init
 };

})(window);

test.init({ size: 300 });
```